# AngularJs response time

Tags: angularjs

I've got a `factory` that's fired with every request to receive the employee:

```
firstname;
companyid;
employeeid;
```

The factory looks like this:

```
(function()
{
    angular.module('employeeApp').factory('authenticationFactory', authenticationFactory);

function authenticationFactory($cookieStore,$cookies,requestFactory,$location,GLOBALS,constants)
{
var factory = {};
factory.valid

ateUser = function()
    {
        var vm = this;
        vm.firstname = constants.firstname;
        vm.companyid = constants.companyid;
        vm.companyid = constants.employeeid;

        if($location.path() != '/')
        {
            var api_token = factory.getToken();

            factory.isValidToken(api_token).then(function(response) {
                if (response.status != 200) {
                    $location.path('/');
                }
                data = {"api_token": api_token};
                requestFactory.post(GLOBALS.url + 'show/employee/' + $cookies.get('employeeid'), data)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        vm.firstname = response.data.result.Employee.FirstName;
                        vm.companyid = response.data.result.Employee.CompanyId;
                        vm.employeeid = response.data.result.Employee.EmployeeId;
                    }, function () {
                        $location.path('/');
                    });
            });
        }
    }
```

When I want to show employees from a company I've got this url:

```
domain.com/show/employees/{companyid}
```

This is my controller for showing all companies:

```
(function()
{
    angular.module('employeeApp').controller('homeController', homeController);

    function homeController(employeeFactory,$cookieStore,$location,constants) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.employees = {};
        vm.constants = constants;
        vm.showEmployees = function()
        {
            employeeFactory.getEmployees(vm.constants.companyid)
                .then(function(response)
                {
                    vm.employees = response;
                }),
                function(){
                    $location.path('/');
                };
        }

        vm.showEmployees();
```

The problem is that the response of the `authenticationFactory` is being fired after the `homeController`so the result is that `vm.constants.companyid` in my `homeController` is empty.

```
angular.js:11500 POST http://domain.dev/api/v1/show/employees/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

How could I fix this?

Thankyou.

Comment: Not clear how authentication works. Does homeController  require login first?

Comment: when does $cookies.get('employeeid') gets populated?

Comment: I check that in my homeController: `factory.isValidToken(api_token).then(function(response) {` after that I set the variables with the employee information.

Comment: @A.B when the user signs in.

Comment: @jamie your problem lies with  `$cookies.get('employeeid')` or `data` notwith order

Comment: @A.B that's not the  problem. If I console.log the response there is a response. The problem is that the response is finished after the homecontroller is initialized.

Comment: Use a resolve in router to make sure authentication is complete. Otherwise need to share authentication promise in `employeefactory` and make request within `then` of the authentication promise

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, but then I've to do that for every route right?

Comment: See update in the comment about sharing the auth promise

Comment: @charlietfl could you give an example?

Comment: @charlietfl if I try resolve router than I've got the same problem.

Comment: not if the auth is what you resolve

Comment: @charlietfli that's right but then I've to resolve it in every route.